# Make a jpg a Shape

Tags: java, image, image-processing, awt

Is there a way to make a file stored as a jpg image into a [Shape](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html)? So, I have a image and an ArrayList and need a way to add that image to the list. The image is a rectangle so is there perhaps a way to store a Rectangle Shape and paint the image inside of the rectangle, maybe?

Comment: I think you can call the method `getRect()` on a loaded `ImageIcon`.

Comment: Thanks! Any way I could ask you for a quick example?

Comment: You cook create a wrapper class which associates a Rectangle and image together or use a Map of some kind

Comment: @AlexT. You have a link to the JavaDocs for that?

Comment: @MadProgrammer, can you explain that in more detail? Early on in my CS career?

Comment: @SupposedlySleeping What is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: The core of it is that I have a PaintObject object that consists of a Shape and a Color. My project spec (Paint App for a CS course) specifies that I must be able to draw an ellipse, a rectangle, a line and a _scalable_ _jpg_. I have been using Recangle2D.Float (etc) for the Shapes. For the sake of functionality, I have added a boolean to the PaintObject class that specifies if a rectangle is in fact supposed to filled with its Color or filled with the jpg. If the boolean returns true, I basically paint a rectangle, then, over the rectangle, paint the scaled image. It's really messy though.